# Open Source XMPP Implementations?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am looking for a library of some sort to handle XMPP in Windows Phone 7. The only thing I have seen mentions the Matrix XMPP SDK but this appears to be a commercial product.

Are there are any free XMPP implementations for Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/) is a open source XMPP implementation, which also supports Windows Phone.

Yes, it's dual-licensed, with GPL being the open source license. If you need a implementation using a MIT/Apache style license, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Ahh I see that MatriX was formed from this product. Unfortunately I suspect GPL isn't going to be suitable for the project I am working on so that is a little bit of an issue. Thanks for the answer